# Is it possible to search by entry number on the front-end?

Tags: search, entry

Is there a way to allow logged in users to search on the front-end by ID number?

I’ve got a list of entries here (http://dev.andover-tc.gov.uk/allotments/maintenance).

What I need to do is setup the search box at the top of the page to allow logged in users to type an entry_id number in and only that entry be displayed.

I’m thinking I may be able to use the URL to control this (i.e. allotments/maintenance/147) but can’t work out how to take the data from an input field and use this to create a URL.

Alternatively, if there’s an easier way I’m open to that too.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [EvoPost](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/evopost) to take the submitted value and send the user to a link. I wrote up a blog post about doing that [here](http://caffeinecreations.ca/blog/a-mostly-out-of-the-box-quiz-with-expressionengine). But essentially you'll create your form and have the action url for that form go to a template in your site that has the following or similar code:

```
{exp:evopost:getpostdata}
  {redirect="/template_group/template_name/{ep_entry_id}/"}
{/exp:evopost:getpostdata}
```

And voila you'll be pulling up the correct entry.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like [Mo Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) to access $_GET, then do something like this in your 'search' template:

```
{redirect="/entry/path/{get:entry_id}"}
```

Then just have your search form do this:

```
<form action="pathto/quicksearch-template" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="entry_id">
</form>
```